# Linux Bash cp wildcards (Question Marks) not working, showing that ???? is not a file or directory

Tags: bash, wildcard, cp

Recently I've been trying to pick up Linux bash commands (Using win-bash) and I was intrigued by wildcards so I decided to try them out. I had my friend create a folder containing random files with random strings and I want to copy every file that has only 4 characters and it displayed that `???? is not a file or directory`.

I used the command: `cp ???? dir`

So.. can someone explain how does the question marks work and how can I properly utilize the wildcards?

Comment: Are you sure there are files that are exactly 4 characters long?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that there aren't any!

Comment: So... does the extension at the back counts as a character?

Comment: @Kaiskii Yes it does. The extension is part of the name. If you want it without the extensions use `????.*`

Comment: Also, I would like to ask, is it possible to make it so that it copies files that contains the letter c or something similar only? For example like if I had random files named : abb baa ccc caa cbd and I only want those that contains b. how can I achieve this?

Comment: @Kaiskii `find -regex ".*/[ab]*"` for filenames that only contain `a` or `b` any number of times.

Comment: Thanks! If only I can thank you here! / Upvote

Answer (score 3):

`bash` treats `????` as a glob, and tries to replace it with a list of any files matching it. If that match fails, then it leaves it as a literal string, rather than raising an error that it cannot find any matches. This literal string is then passed to `cp`, which cannot find a file named "????", and so *it* raises the error you see.